# Laravel one app with multiple subdomains?

Tags: php, laravel, dns, subdomain, laravel-forge

I need to have one main Laravel application, and what I want to achieve is having a subdomain, for ex:
cars.domain.com -> point to Route group cars, sedans.domain.com -> point to Route group sedans, suvs.domain.com -> point to Route group suvs

So each subdomain points to a route group? I am using AWS + Laravel Forge, how should I setup the Laravel app + the DNS so it can function like that? And can it work like that, or should I use a different approach?

Because the other things that I considered is making branches for each subdomain and then in Laravel Forge create a subdomain that will point to a branch, for ex: cars.domain.com -> points to "cars" branch and so on..

Which approach should I use to get it working? Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Well I think I found a solution, with the Subdomain routing Laravel offers: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-subdomain-routing